# Get remote address when using jersey with embedded grizzly

Tags: jersey, grizzly

I have been searching for a solution to this problem with no success. The latest posts I found date back to 2010. I am using jersey 1.12 with embedded grizzly 2.2.1.

If I understood correctly, unless I deploy my jersey resources under a servlet container I cannot inject HttpServletRequest in them. Is there a workaround?

Comment: http://www.jroller.com/iangreen/entry/getting_remote_host_using_jersey seems to be the post you are referring to

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17233960/how-can-i-get-my-hands-on-client-addresses-for-logging-using-grizzly-jersey has some code that might work

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
@Context org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.Request req
```

Example usage:

```
@Path("/example")
public class SomeResource {

  @POST
  @Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
  public void someMethod(@Context Request req) {
    System.out.println(req.getRemoteAddr());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case we had a standalone Jersey cluster running behind nginx as a load balancer. 
Thus workaround was to make it pass remote address as a request header, which is also easily accessible from Jersey:

```
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```