# How can I get my hands on client addresses for logging using Grizzly / Jersey?

Tags: java, jersey, logback, grizzly

I'm using Grizzly to serve a Jersey application, while using Logback for my logging needs. Please not that there are no `Servlet`s involved here, I fire up everything "by hand" using a piece of code like this:

```java
final URI uri = /* this is a configuration option */        
this.server = new HttpServer();
final NetworkListener nl = new NetworkListener(
    "grizzly", uri.getHost(), uri.getPort());
server.addListener(nl);

final GuiceComponentProviderFactory gcpf =
    new GuiceComponentProviderFactory(rc, inj);
final HttpHandler processor = ContainerFactory.createContainer(
    HttpHandler.class, rc, gcpf);
this.server.getServerConfiguration().addHttpHandler(
    processor, uri.getPath());
server.start();
```

Now I would like to use Logback's [MDC](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html) feature to make the socket address of the clients visible in the log records. For this purpose I would need some place to hook up a listener to the HTTP processing which gets notified about incoming requests (where I can put the address into the MDC) and when a request is done (so I can clean up the MDC). One approach I followed is to hook up a `Container*Filter` instance with Jersey, which looked like this:

```java
class MdcFilter implements
        ContainerRequestFilter, ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Override
    public ContainerRequest filter(ContainerRequest request) {
        MDC.put("http-client", "foo" /* no way to get the address here */);
        return request;
    }

    @Override
    public ContainerResponse filter(
            ContainerRequest request,
            ContainerResponse response) {

        MDC.remove("http-client");
        return response;
    }

}
```

Unfortunately, a Jersey `ContainerRequest` does not provide information about the connected client (which cam as a real surprise).

I suspect a similar interface should exist with Grizzly itself, but I was unable to dig it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Grizzly, the relevant API is called [`HttpServerProbe`](https://grizzly.java.net/docs/2.3/apidocs/org/glassfish/grizzly/http/server/HttpServerProbe.html). Using this, it comes down to something like this:

```
final HttpServer server = new org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServer();
server.addListener(new NetworkListener("grizzly", "localhost", 8080));
server.getServerConfiguration().addHttpHandler(
    new StaticHttpHandler("/var/www/"), "/");

server.getServerConfiguration().getMonitoringConfig().getWebServerConfig()
  .addProbes(new HttpServerProbe.Adapter() {

    @Override
    public void onRequestReceiveEvent(
        HttpServerFilter filter,
        Connection connection,
        Request request) {

      System.out.println(request.getRemoteAddr());
      MDC.put("http-client", request.getRemoteAddr());
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestCompleteEvent(
        HttpServerFilter filter,
        Connection connection,
        Response response) {

      MDC.remove("http-client");
    }
}

server.start();
```

Note that there are more events which might be relevant, like suspend, resume and cancel. These should probably be handled as well, especially if long-polling (aka Comet, aka *whatnot*) is used. But basically this is the place to hook into.

Comment: This only seems to work if the server is started in a specific way. Would you please share the code that starts the server for comparison.

Comment: I extended the above example code to be runnable and just checked that it actually works, @WolfgangFahl. Let me know if there are problems with this.

Comment: Thanks - I also got it working now. Unfortunately the GrizzlyServerFactory code has no option *not* to start the server. When adding the the monitoring after starting the server it seems to have no effect.

Comment: Thanks Waldheinz (upvote) for the hint on how to use manual probes. With the addition of Wolfgang, your solution as well as the more simplified [Access Logging](https://grizzly.java.net/httpserverframework.html#Access_Logging) is now working like a charm.

Answer (score -1):

In your `MdcFilter`, try to inject the `HttpServletRequest` into your class and use that as you would normally to call `getRemoteAddr()` or any other such function as in:

```
class MdcFilter implements
    ContainerRequestFilter, ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Context
    protected HttpServletRequest r;

    @Override
    public ContainerRequest filter(ContainerRequest request) {
        MDC.put("http-client", "foo" r.getRemoteAddr());
        return request;
    }

    @Override
    public ContainerResponse filter(ContainerRequest request, ContainerResponse response) {
        MDC.remove("http-client");
        return response;
    }
}
```

I tested this out using a similar approach to "firing things up by hand" and it worked out for me in that case.  I assume it would work for you as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no `HttpServletRequest` available in my case. I even had to pull in a new dependency (I opted for `servlet-api` in version 2.5) to have that interface available. But even then, it's not getting injected. It's causing an `NullPointerException` when dereferencing `r`.